# How do I start KDE Desktop via X11? CentOS 7

Tags: centos, x11, kde

I wonder how to start the KDE Desktop via X11 on my CentOS 7.

So I installed:

```
    yum groupinstall "KDE Plasma Workspaces" -y
```

and set:

```
    systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

I am using `putty` from a Windows 10 client with working ssh login and I set the "Enable X11 forwarding". I also installed `Xming` and tried `xclock&` and `xeyes&` in my terminal.

Both are working like a charm.

Comment: try startkde but forwarding a whole XSession might be a pain. Consider using something like vnc

Comment: so when I already installed KDE and set it to graphical.target and my VPS-host already provided a VCN login for me, so I should see the GUI via UltraVNC or?

Comment: As long as vnc is running on the host and there is nothing blocking its service port

Comment: [screenshot](http://vault.georodin.bplaced.net/media/mistake.PNG)
I guess the GUI is somehow stuck, I restarted once with Ctrl + Alt + Del

Comment: well it is working now, thanks a lot <3
had to use "systemctl isolate graphical.target" once more

Comment: Add this as an answer

Comment: it´s only a part of the answer, seems like if only manage to install incomplete desktop environments
because its just displaying a infinite spinning cent os loading screen
so I tried installing/uninstalling KDE, Gnom and Cinnamon, and only with cinnamon I get smth like a desktop(otherwise only loading page), but I get is also only openbox working instead of cinnamon with or without software rendering and Xfce Session, everything else send me to the login page after login, and KDE and Gnome I even dont got to the login page
so dats why I cant answer now, I need more knowledge ^^

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problems.

First I had to uninstall old and unnecessary groups with the commands
`yum grouplist` to find them and to remove `yum groups remove "enter group name"`

then I made a clean install of GNOME with `yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"`
when the installation was finished I run once `startx` and the desktop appeared in my VNC-Viewer

keep in mind that you probably have too keep your VNC-Server while uninstalling unnecessary groups, when its not provided by your VPS-Host like in my case